# Cannot call an entrypoint with a name bigger than 31 chars

Tags: multisig, entrypoint

One of my contract has been successfully compiled and deployed (as well as audited). I discovered however that one of my entrypoint as more characters than 31 chars... This entrypoint can only be called through a multisig. So what I'm doing usually is to build a lambda and then inject it into the multisig. Now, octez-client refuse to build the lambda because it says the entrypoint as more than 3 chars.
Do you know if there is a way to call the entrypoint despite this error ?
[image]

Comment: I tried on ghostnet without the multisig and I got a "OversizedEntryPointError"... This means I cannot most likely not call the entrypoint. How can this pass compilation on SmartPy ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but entrypoint length is indeed bounded.

Comment: I guess the alternative is to call the contract with the explicit argument and forgot about the name of the entrypoint. I will try that.